# pandas make lines of text file into columns by name

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i have a text file that looks like this:

```
Tag: liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_12.3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson
  Global path: /net/liosprod8.cvc-global.net/export/viewstore/liprod/liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_12.3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson.vws
  Server host: liosprod8.cvc-global.net
  Region: cssall
  Active: NO
  View tag uuid:ccd335a4.fb8011eb.af37.00:50:56:bf:58:95
View on host: liosprod8.cvc-global.net
View server access path: /export/viewstore/liprod/liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_12.3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson.vws
View uuid: ccd335a4.fb8011eb.af37.00:50:56:bf:58:95
View attributes: snapshot
View owner: tmn/liprod

Tag: liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_DF3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson
  Global path: /net/liosprod8.cvc-global.net/export/viewstore/liprod/liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_DF3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson.vws
  Server host: liosprod8.cvc-global.net
  Region: cssall
  Active: NO
  View tag uuid:dc2ff6f7.fb8311eb.bb47.00:50:56:bf:58:95
View on host: liosprod8.cvc-global.net
View server access path: /export/viewstore/liprod/liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_DF3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson.vws
View uuid: dc2ff6f7.fb8311eb.bb47.00:50:56:bf:58:95
View attributes: snapshot
View owner: tmn/liprod
```

I want to make an excel to have the output like this:

[image: output]

The output should have put the datas from the lines into correct columns, and when he find new "Tag" to put in on a new line.

example:

```
Tag                                                GlobalPath                                  ...

liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_12.3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson     /net/liosprod8.cvc-global.net/export/viewst...

liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_DF3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson      //net/liosprod8.cvc-global.net/export/v....
```

I have also made a script, but its not having the expected output:   https://paste.pythondiscord.com/obulosuvuy

Maybe if you know another variant using pandas or you know what i did wrong in my script...

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`StringMethods.split`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.split.html) to split into 2 cols then [**`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape :

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('test.txt', header=None)

df[['col1','col2']] = df[0].str.split(pat=":", n=1, expand=True)

cols = df['col1'].str.strip().drop_duplicates().tolist()

out = (
        df.pivot(columns="col1", values="col2")
          .assign(Tag = lambda x: x['Tag'].ffill())
          .groupby('Tag').sum()
          .replace(0, 'N/A')
          .reset_index()
          .rename_axis(axis=1, mapper=None)
          .rename(columns= lambda x: x.strip())
          .reindex(columns=cols)
        )

out.to_excel('your_excel_name.xlsx', index=False) #to save a spreadsheet
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

                                                          Tag                                                                                                Global path                Server host   Region Active                             View tag uuid               View on host                                                       View server access path                                  View uuid View attributes   View owner
0              liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_12.3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson   /net/liosprod8.cvc-global.net/export/viewstore/liprod/liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_12.3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson.vws   liosprod8.cvc-global.net   cssall     NO  ccd335a4.fb8011eb.af37.00:50:56:bf:58:95   liosprod8.cvc-global.net   /export/viewstore/liprod/liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_12.3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson.vws   ccd335a4.fb8011eb.af37.00:50:56:bf:58:95        snapshot   tmn/liprod
1               liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_DF3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson    /net/liosprod8.cvc-global.net/export/viewstore/liprod/liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_DF3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson.vws   liosprod8.cvc-global.net   cssall     NO  dc2ff6f7.fb8311eb.bb47.00:50:56:bf:58:95   liosprod8.cvc-global.net    /export/viewstore/liprod/liprod_Liosprod8_LIOS_DF3_NIGHT_linux8_hudson.vws   dc2ff6f7.fb8311eb.bb47.00:50:56:bf:58:95        snapshot   tmn/liprod
2   liprod_simpleSlave_LIOS_86_LATEST_MNT_hudson_dynamic_view    /net/rhliprod.cvc-global.net/export/viewstore/liprod_simpleSlave_LIOS_86_LATEST_MNT_hudson_dynamic_view    rhliprod.cvc-global.net   cssall     NO  de5ddadb.3e0011ed.91ef.00:0c:29:84:11:a7    rhliprod.cvc-global.net   /export/viewstore/liprod_simpleSlave_LIOS_86_LATEST_MNT_hudson_dynamic_view   de5ddadb.3e0011ed.91ef.00:0c:29:84:11:a7             N/A   tmn/liprod
```

Comment: and if its no data in some line will fill that column with "n/a" or something? cause i have a 3rd line that dont have 1 line and its putting bad the datas

Comment: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/zebiritale test with this file, to see that the line 3 on xlsx file its not good cauuse a line is misissing in the .txt file

Comment: works good now, ty , FutureWarning: As the xlwt package is no longer maintained, the xlwt engine will be removed in a future version of pandas. This is the only engine in pandas that supports writing in the xls format. Install openpyxl and write to an xlsx file instead. You can set the option io.excel.xls.writer to 'xlwt' to silence this warning. While this option is deprecated and will also raise a warning, it can be globally set and the warning suppressed.
  out.to_excel(os.path.join(dest, "ClearcaseViews.xls"), index=False) idea what its with this error?

Comment: oh i found, because of xls , not writinng on xlsx. solved

Comment: imgur.com/a/hMPwoO6 i have this error on im trying to use the script on a bigger file, any ideea why? https://paste.pythondiscord.com/agelelimik.py this is the file @abokey .i think its because i have View attributes: snapshot,webview instead as in the beggining with only View attributes: snapshot

Comment: You're right @Champs, this is because the `sep` parameter is by default `,` in `pd.read_csv`. Use `pd.read_fwf` instead. I updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: yes, i solved , i used a "sep="'|" " now, and its working .. but i have also some problem in another script, like was working for a smaller file, but when i added more data its not, can i put here the S.O link of post maybe can give me a hint or help? @abokey

Comment: Is this the one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73908181/pandas-parsed-error-expected-1-fields-saw-2 ? If no, open a new question and we'll see.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911427/pandas-fetch-line-from-datas-into-columns this is the link @abokey

Answer (score 0):

You made it overly complicated. If your file always have the same structure (records separated by an empty line and the same 11 fields for each record) you can just do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd

data=[]

with open ("input.txt") as file:
    content=file.read()
    records=content.split("\n\n")

    for r in records:
        line_data=[]
        for line in r.splitlines():
            value=line.split(":")[1].strip()
            line_data.append(value)
        data.append(line_data)

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[
    "Tag",
    "Global path",
    "Server host",
    "Region",
    "Active",
    "View tag uuid",
    "View on host",
    "View server access path",
    "View uuid",
    "View attributes",
    "View owner"
])

df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

Basically what it does is separating the records by using .split("\n\n"), then for each line of them extract what is after ":" and put in in an appropriate data structure (a list of lists) that is used to build the DataFrame.

Comment: its working but not 100% corectly, https://imgur.com/a/K1Z76Q9

Comment: on the last line its not adding the view.attributes cause dont exist, how can add a .fillna ith "N/A"?

Comment: like i want a "N/A" if on that columns is no data or something as in the img photo i send, the view attirbutes lines dont exist, so nothing will be displayed on that column for that line

Comment: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/agelelimik i try to use the script on this file but i have this error idk what means https://imgur.com/a/vb2T3OD if you can help me