# Pandas parsed error ,expected 1 fields, saw 2

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sparse-matrix

i have a problem.

This is the script:

```
def clearcaseviews():
    pathdest = path_dir()
    dest = createdir()
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


    df=pd.read_csv(rf"{pathdest}\{timestr}-clearcaseRawData-viewDetails.txt",header=None)
    df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[0].str.split(pat=":", n=1, expand=True)

    cols = df['col1'].str.strip().drop_duplicates().tolist()

    out = (
        df.pivot(columns="col1", values="col2")
            .assign(Tag=lambda x: x['Tag'].ffill())
            .groupby('Tag').sum()
            .replace(0, 'N/A')
            .reset_index()
            .rename_axis(axis=1, mapper=None)
            .rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
            .reindex(columns=cols)
    )


    out.to_excel(os.path.join(dest, "ClearcaseViews.xlsx"), index=False)
```

This is the file datas (some of but its reppetly):

```
Tag: ccweb_Test
  Global path: <no-gpath>
  Server host: atpcs7dc-1.cvc-global.net
  Region: cssall
  Active: NO
  View tag uuid:6cf9366a.c88d11da.9e26.00:0c:29:01:2f:0c
View on host: atpcs7dc-1.ww300.siemens.net
View server access path: /var/adm/rational/clearcase/ccweb/ccweb/ccweb_Test/.view.stg
View uuid: 6cf9366a.c88d11da.9e26.00:0c:29:01:2f:0c
View attributes: snapshot,webview
View owner: ccweb

Tag: sonne_liosBuild_8.2night
  Global path: /net/atvies00mx/export/home/liprod/build_system/continuum-1.2.3/data/working-directory/\atvies00mxviewstoresonne_liosBuild_8.2night.vws
  Server host: atvies00mx
  Region: cssall
  Active: NO
  View tag uuid:d9a33bc5.1acf11de.8bac.00:01:80:81:80:3c
View on host: atvies00mx.cvc-global.net
View server access path: /export/home/liprod/build_system/continuum-1.2.3/data/working-directory/\atvies00mxviewstoresonne_liosBuild_8.2night.vws
View uuid: d9a33bc5.1acf11de.8bac.00:01:80:81:80:3c
View attributes: snapshot
View owner: tnobs/liprod

Tag: march
  Global path: /net/atvies2c1x/RAID5/viewstore/sdf/march.vws
  Server host: atvies2c1x.cvc-global.net
  Region: cssall
  Active: NO
  View tag uuid:51363d16.ad9711dd.843a.00:01:80:81:80:3c
View on host: atvies2c1x.cvc-global.net
View server access path: /RAID5/viewstore/sdf/march.vws
View uuid: 51363d16.ad9711dd.843a.00:01:80:81:80:3c
View owner: tnobs/atw10rt7
```

And this is the error i have:
[image: error]

The error is because of the lines where the script finds two attributes, and he dont know that he should put them on the same column line..

Comment: read_csv use comma (,) as the default separator, add sep='|' (or some other character that is not in the file)

Comment: can you explain? i didnt understand

Comment: the line "View attributes: snapshot,webview" contains a comma that read_csv sees as a separator by default. use pd.read_csv(your_file_path, header=None, sep='|') when reading the file, so it will not try to read webview as a part of a separated column.

Comment: yes, works now, ty